# Use DisplayFormat within a custom DisplayTemplate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

If you've defined a custom DisplayTemplate, is there some way to use the `DisplayFormat.DataFormatString` defined for that object?

For example, I've defined a DisplayTemplate for `Double`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("", ViewData["label"] as string, new { @class = "col-sm-6" })
    <p class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m)
    </p>
</div>
```

Then my model defines a DisplayFormat:

```
[Display(Name = "In Weight")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0} lb")]
public double? InWeight{ get; set; }
```

In the above example, `DisplayTextFor` only provides a simple ToString(), while replacing it with `DisplayFor` renders nothing.

Comment: Why are you using `@Html.Label()` when you do not have an associated form control. The reason `DisplayFor()` would not work is that it would keep calling itself. You could access the properties `ModelMetadata` to generate the formatted value

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right, it's probably more appropriate to use a `dl` description list in this case, but the question would be the same for formatting the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m)` method does not take into account the `DisplayFormatAttribute` and `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)` does not work because it would be recursively calling itself creating an endless loop. You need to access the properties `ModelMetadata`.

Note also you are not generating a form control, so use of a `<label>` element would not be appropriate.

Your template should look something like

```
@model System.Double
<div>
    <div>@ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()</div>
    <div>@string.Format(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString ?? "{0:0.00}", Model)</div>
</div>
```

and add class names to the enclosing elements to style it

Note I have added a 'default' format for properties where the `[DisplayFormat]` may not be applied.

Side note: Since the property is `nullable`, you could also enhance this further by including something like

```
@if (Model == null)
{
    <div>@(ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText ?? "Not assigned")</div>
}
else
{
    <div>@string.Format(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString ?? "{0:0.00}", Model)</div>
}
```

Comment: I could never get string.format working for me here, had to end up going with DateValue.ToString(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString); Although granted, I was working with an individual property.